# proxy doesn't protect from geo-pigeonholing

Tags: privacy

some sites always manifest as your country of ip.  i hate that, so i got firefox plugin 'anonymox' to stop teh nets from narrowing my world to a sliver. however, lately some sites have seen through that and have redirected me despite the presence of the proxy.  i wrote to anonymox about it, asking how that could happen; they mentioned javascript that sees through proxies and recommended i check out an article on it, the only obstacle to my instant edifcation being that it was in danish, finish or swedish [which escapes me rt now]. 
well that was definitely as case of tldnr, especially teh suggestion i employ ggl translate for a nice dodgy version of the text.

can anyone enlighten me/point me in the direction of some reading in english as to how to anonymise PROPLY???

Comment: use Vidalia pack (privoxy and TOR) or use a FoxyProxy with Firefox https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/foxyproxy-standard/

You can also use anonymouse proxy from this list: http://spys.ru/en/anonymous-proxy-list/ and set it up with foxyproxy. You can disable javascript with NoScript addon and block java virtual machine from connection to the internet. This will keep you anonymouse in the internet at a satisfying level.

Answer (score 1):

You can read something about [TOR](https://www.torproject.org/), which should be what you are looking for.

Comment: thankyou for your help.  i have read that Tor does not permit perfectly anonymous browsing but rather something more like being 'hidden in plain view' among many.  do you have any thoughts on that?

Comment: @adrfa the main problem about Tor is that the traffic from the exit node to the destination in unencrypted: if a malicious user happens to be there he would be able to see your traffic. This said though, Tor is used in situations where high security is needed, so in a normal situation it should be enough...

Comment: i see.  so if i use both tor and a proxy, would that stop the geo-pigeonholing?

Comment: @adrfa usually the proxy used in combination with Tor is Privoxy. It should definitely help, though I am not sure if it will completely cancel the problem...